# Join two Json arrays to one with key and value

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I have two jsonb columns(keys,values).
Eg: keys colum value = `["key1","key2","key3","key4"]`
values column = `["val1","val2","val3","val4"]`

I want to write a select query to get the output as below based on the array index.

```
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4"}
```

Comment: This is existing table structure. Cannot change that. But output need as a single key value json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the arrays then aggregate everything back into a single JSON value:

```
select x.value
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_object_agg(k.ky, v.value) as value
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(t.keys) with ordinality as k(ky,idx)
       join jsonb_array_elements(t.values) with ordinality as v(value,idx) on k.idx = v.idx
  ) x
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=39cea2aa985c5651df5ea2cb50eb637b)